# Custom command with server yml command in Dropwizard

Tags: yaml, dropwizard

I have this custom Command:

```
public final class ArgsCommand extends Command {

    private String foobar;

    private String baz;

    public ArgsCommand() {
        super("args", "sets additional application arguments");
    }

    public String getFoobar() {
        return foobar;
    }

    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Subparser subparser) {
        subparser.addArgument("-foobar")
                .dest("foobar")
                .type(String.class)
                .required(true)
                .help("the foobar value for the application");

        subparser.addArgument("-baz")
                .dest("baz")
                .type(String.class)
                .required(true)
                .help("the baz value for the application");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(Bootstrap<?> bootstrap, Namespace namespace) throws Exception {
        foobar = namespace.getString("foobar");
        baz = namespace.getString("baz");

        if (foobar == null || foobar.length() == 0
                || baz == null || baz.length() == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "One or more required command-line arguments is missing!");
        }

        // do something with the additional arguments
    }
}
```

...set in the Application as follows:

```
@Override
public void initialize(final Bootstrap<FoobarBazConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addCommand(new ArgsCommand());
}
```

...and executed from the command-line as follows:

```
java -jar <jar file> args -foobar asdf -baz 123
```

---

I would like to do this (*not working*):

```
java -jar <jar file> server <yml file> args -foobar asdf -baz 123
```

Do I now need a custom command argument to pass and handle the .yml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so taking a different approach, this was easier than I thought --

1) -- Add custom key/value pairs to the .yml configuration file:

```
foobar: asdf
baz: 123
```

2) -- Register the custom keys in FoobarBazConfiguration.java:

```
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public final class FoobarBazConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @NotEmpty
    private String foobar;

    @NotEmpty
    private String baz;

    @JsonProperty("foobar")
    public String getFoobar() {
        return foobar;
    }

    @JsonProperty("foobar")
    public void setFoobar(String foobar) {
        this.foobar = foobar;
    }

    @JsonProperty("baz")
    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    @JsonProperty("baz")
    public void setBaz(String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }
}
```

3) -- Retrieve the values from your configuration object in FoobarBazApplication.java:

```
System.out.println(configuration.getFoobar());
System.out.println(configuration.getBaz());
```

4) -- Run the application from the command-line as per usual:

```
java -jar <jar file> server <yml file>
```

---

I still don't know how to use a subclass of `Command` with `server <.yml file>` though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested key/value pairs in the .yml file, you can use a `Map<String, String>`:

1) -- Add custom key/value pairs to the .yml configuration file:

```
args:
  foobar: asdf
  baz: 123
```

2) -- Register the Map in FoobarBazConfiguration.java:

```
import io.dropwizard.Configuration;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public final class FoobarBazConfiguration extends Configuration {

    @NotEmpty
    private Map<String, String> args;

    @JsonProperty("args")
    public Map<String, String> getArgs() {
        return args;
    }

    @JsonProperty("args")
    public void setArgs(Map<String, String> args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getFoobar() {
        return args.get("foobar");
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getBaz() {
        return args.get("baz");
    }
}
```

3) -- Retrieve the values from your configuration object in FoobarBazApplication.java:

```
System.out.println(configuration.getFoobar());
System.out.println(configuration.getBaz());
```